# nhibernate spi initialization error

Tags: nhibernate

I have just started using NHibernate, and I am using the Quick Start Guide but I keep getting this Error.I have done everything exactly the way the Quick Start Guide says to do it and I get this Error every time.

```
<error>
{"The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an exception."}
</error>
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
Configuration nhConfig = new Configuration();
```

With the Inner Exception being:

```
<Inner Exception>
{"The type initializer for 'log4net.spi.LoggerManager' threw an exception."}
</Inner Exception>
```

And the Stack Trace of the Inner Exception:

```
<Stack Trace>
"   at log4net.spi.LoggerManager.GetLogger(Assembly domainAssembly, String name)\r\n        at log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly domainAssembly, String name)\r\n   at    log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Type type)\r\n   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..cctor()"
</Stack Trace>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"That almost looks like a log4net exception. Log4net is also not supposed to throw any exceptions outside of its assembly. "